# python: Change pyttsx abbreviations

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I've been trying to set up my pyttsx. I have so far got it to achieve reading a sentence. I would like to know how to change abbreviations e.g

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate -12)
engine.say('INC0055 16/11/13 13:59 RESPOND GRASS FIRE, ALARM LEVEL: 3)
engine.runAndWait()
```

As you can see, the INC stands for incident number but python reads it as include. How can I change this?

Cheers

Shane

P.s changing the INC to say incident is not an option

Comment: If this snippet is what you have in your script then you have forgotten `'`. It should be `engine.say('INC0055 16/11/13 13:59 RESPOND GRASS FIRE, ALARM LEVEL: 3')`

Comment: I see i know what i did was removed some infor and forgot the ' but when it plays its says INC as induce i want it to say incident instead

Comment: What OS/speach engine do you use?

Comment: ubuntu and windows and standard engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) is used by default in linux. On windows - SAPI5 by Microsoft. Sorry no luck for SAPI but for eSpeak you can add explicit pronunciation of word rather easily (not quite abbreviation change but it should be of use).

All you need is source for language dictionary file (`en_list` for english). You can get it with source of eSpeak from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/files/espeak/espeak-1.47/). I've taken `espeak-1.47.11-source.zip`.

Then I've went to `espeak-1.47.11-source/dictsource` dir, opened `en_list` and entered one line (just before *incense*):

```
inc Insi:dEnt
```

Then I've compiled dictionary with (it will place `en_dict` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/espeak-data/en_dict`)

```
$ sudo espeak --compile English
```

Note that after the word pronanciation goes see [here for the detail](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/dictionary.html). That's all. Now my notebook speaks *incident* instead of *inc*. Besides it never told me *include* in place of *inc*.

Comment: so now what python command do i type to use espeak with python on windows ?

Comment: it should be `engine = pyttsx.init('espeak')` but I didn't try it either